# how to show that $\sum_{ n=1}^{∞ }a_n^+ = ∞ $?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n \in \mathbb R$, such that $\sum_{ n=1}^{\infty }|a_n| = \infty $ and  $\sum_{ n=1}^{m }a_n \ \rightarrow a\in \mathbb R$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$. Let $a_n ^+= \max\{a_n,0\}.$

Show that $\sum_{ n=1}^{\infty }a_n^+ = \infty $.

---

My attempts : I was thinking like this

$$|a_n|=a_n^{+}- a_n^{-}  $$
$$\sum_{ n=1}^{\infty }|a_n|=\sum_{ n=1}^{∞ }a_n^{+} -\sum_{ n=1}^{\infty }a_n^{-}$$

After that I can't proceed further.

Please help me  and tell me the solution or any hints can be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Write $2a_n^+=a_n+|a_n|$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  according to ur hints i get $$|a_n|=a_n^{+}- a_n^{-}  $$

$$|a_n| +a_n^{+} =a_n^{+}- a_n^{-} +a_n^{+}  $$

$$|a_n| +a_n^{+} =2a_n^{+}- a_n^{-}$$

$$2a_n^{+}=|a_n| +a_n^{+} +a_n^{-}$$  ,,,my question is  that from where $ a_n $come ? im not getting  how $$a_n =a_n^{+} +a_n^{-}$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be restated as finding a sum of all positive elements of the series. The series is convergent, but not absolutely convergent, so its positive elements alone and negative elements alone produce divergent series.